# Correct way to implement inherited static methods for JSON deserialization

Tags: json, oop, dart, serialization

This question is about Dart, but can also extend to the larger "object oriented programming paradigm" as well.

I am trying to build a JSON serializer/deserializer framework for my Flutter app to interface with my Firestore database. I have a set of models that I have created (`Account`, `Transaction`, and `Person`). I have functions for each serializing them into JSON and named constructors deserializing them from JSON. I also have a function that creates a converter for each model for the Firestore interface as per the guide on the [Flutter Cloud Firestore tutorial page](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/) so that I do not have to deserialize / serialize every transaction with the Firestore database into one of these models.

I am trying to create a common, polymorphic function that will take either the `Account`, `Person`, or `Transaction` class and make a converter for Firestore for it. It kind of looks like this:

```dart
dynamic createFirestorRef<T extends Entity>(FirebaseFirestore instance) {
  return instance.collection("accounts").withConverter<T>(
        fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) {
          return T.fromJson(snapshot.id, snapshot.data()!);
        },
        toFirestore: (entity, _) => entity.toJson(),
      );
}
```

Where the "`Entity`" class is the common inherited abstract class between the three other classes that implements the `.toJson()` method. However, the `.fromJson()` method is a named constructor of Entity and is therefore NOT inherited by the child classes and therefore won't follow the polymorphic behavior that `.toJson()` does. Therefore, this line `return T.fromJson(snapshot.id, snapshot.data()!);` does not work as there is no way to ensure that classes that inherit from Entity have a named constructor called `.fromJson()`.

My question is: **how do I replicate this behavior that follows the general OOP paradigm?**

Dart has neither inherited static methods nor inherited constructors. I cannot implement a instance method because at the point of deserialization, there is no instance yet.

Comment: You can sort of achieve this with a `Map<Type, Function>` that's initialized with the callbacks you want.  However, the typical way to serialize/deserialize JSON in Dart is to use *code generation*, which is how [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) work.  I strongly recommend using an existing solution instead creating your own.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you for the suggestions for the built in libraries. Is this standard practice for development in Dart? New to this language

Comment: As I said, using code-generation is the typical recommendation.  Manually deserializing JSON can be very error-prone.